# Mongoose with async queue & waterfall

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I aim to import large amount of data by Mongoose. As a newbie, I fail to setup the flow control properly with various mechanisms by async. Glad if someone could point to an appropriate solution. Thanks.

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

// Imagine this is a huge array with a million items.
var content = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
var queries = [];
content.forEach(function(name) {
  queries.push(function(cb) {
    var obj = new Cat({ name: name });
    obj.save(function(err) {
      console.log("SAVED: " + name);
      console.log(err);
    });
    return true;
  });
});

// FAILED: async.parallel adds all content to db, 
// but it would exhaust the resource with too many parallel tasks.
async.parallel(queries, function(err, result) {
  if (err)
    return console.log(err);
  console.log(result);
});

// FAILED: save the first item but not the rest
async.waterfall(queries, function(err, result) {
  if (err)
    return console.log(err);
  console.log(result);
});

// FAILED: same as async.waterfall, async.queue saves the first item only
var q = async.queue(function(name, cb) {
  var obj = new Cat({ name: name });
  obj.save(function(err) {
    console.log("SAVED: " + name);
    console.log(err);
  });
})
q.push(content, function (err) {
  console.log('finished processing queue');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [`eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) or [`eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) fit your situation best:

```
var content = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
async.eachLimit(content, 10, function(name, done) {
  var obj = new Cat({ name : name });
  obj.save(done);
  // if you want to print some status info, use this instead:
  //
  // obj.save(function(err) {
  //   console.log("SAVED: " + name);
  //   console.log(err);
  //   done(err);
  // });
  //
}, function(err) {
  // handle any errors;
});
```

With `eachLimit`, you can run an X amount of queries 'in parallel' (10 in the example above) to speed things up without exhausting resources. `eachSeries` will wait for the previous save before it continues with the next, so effectively saving one object at a time.

Notice that with `each*`, you won't get a list with (saved) objects back (it's a bit of a fire-and-forget mechanism where you're not interested in the outcome, bar any errors). If you do want a list of saved objects in the end, you can use the equivalent `map*` functions: [`mapLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#maplimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) and [`mapSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#mapseriesarr-iterator-callback).

Comment: Thanks @robertklep for answering it. I tried your code (`eachLimit` with limit=1) but it saves the first item of the array only (same as queue and waterfall). Does `eachLimit` finish the rest of the array? What's wrong with my usage of `queue` and `waterfall`?

Comment: I may have figured out. If ``done(err)`` is skipped, it does not run the next iteration. Why is it needed?

Comment: @Unmeow that's how `async` can regulate asynchronous calls. It needs to get notified that an iteration is done, that's what the callback function is used for.